# Find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x^2+p^2)/xp < -2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following inequality for $x\in\mathbb{R}$: $$\frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{xp} < -2, $$
where $p$ is a real parameter.  I want to have my $x$ on the left side and everything else on the right side.

The first step I would take is to multiply both sides of the inequality with $xp$, however I'm not sure how to do so. Do I need to split my solution into 4 branches (1. where $x>0$ and $p<0$, 2. where $x<0$ and $p>0$, 3. where $x>0$ and $p>0$ and 4. where $x<0$ and $p<0$), or can I just simple split it into two branches, where $xp>0$ and where $xp<0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to proceed as follows

$$\frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{xp} < -2\iff \frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{xp} +2<0\iff \frac{x^{2}+2xp+p^{2}}{xp}<0\iff \frac{(x+p)^2}{xp}<0$$

and the sign corresponds to the sign of $xp\ne 0$.

Proceeding by multiplication we have

- $xp>0$

$$\frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{xp} < -2\iff x^2+p^2<-2px \iff (x+p)^2<0$$

which is not possible, and

- $xp<0$

$$\frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{xp} < -2\iff x^2+p^2>-2px \iff (x+p)^2>0$$

which is always true, then $xp<0$ is the solution.

As noticed by Xander Henderson, of course the given solution holds for $x+p\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. So the solution is $(-\infty, 0)$ for $a>0$ and $(0,\infty)$ for a<0?

Comment: @Peter Yes that's right!

Comment: Thanks. And one last question, if I had to multiply it, would I need to branch it into 4 solutions, or just two solutions (the question in my post)?

Comment: @Peter In that case we need to consider two cases $xp>0$ and $xp<0$ and from here you obtain directly the solutions since $(x+p)^2$ can't be negative.

Comment: Yes, but for an example if $xp>0$, then $x>0$ and $p>0$ or $x<0$ and $p<0$. I wanted to know, if I can generalise it as $xp>0$, or if I need to branch $xp>0$ into the two possible branches, where both are negative or both are positive.

Comment: @Peter I'm going to add something on that.

Comment: Consider $x=1$, $p=-1$.  Then $xp < 0$, but $$\frac{x^2 + p^2}{xp} = \frac{1^2+1^2}{(1)(-1)} = -2 \not < -2.$$

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks! Good point

Answer (score 2):

A possible way by splitting in only two branches is as follows using the inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean:

- AM-GM: $a,b\geq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$ and equality holds if and only if $a= b$ (which can be  easily proved by squaring and rearranging).

Cancelling gives

- $\frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{xp} = \frac{x}{p} + \frac{p}{x}$
- Setting $y:=\frac{x}{p}$, you get for $xp>0 \Leftrightarrow y= \frac{x}{p}>0$ the inequality 
  $$y+\frac{1}{y}\stackrel{AM-GM}{>} 2 \Leftrightarrow y\neq 1,y>0$$

It follows immediately for $px<0\Leftrightarrow y= \frac{x}{p}<0$
$$y+\frac{1}{y} < -2 \Leftrightarrow y\neq -1,y<0 \Leftrightarrow  \frac{x}{p}\neq-1,\frac{x}{p}<0 $$

So, the solutions are

- $p>0$: $x\in (-\infty,0)\setminus\{-p\}$
- $p<0$: $x\in (0,+\infty)\setminus\{-p\}$

Comment: Original derivation!

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate things.  You correctly infer that you would like to cancel the $xp$ term, and that this cancelation might change the direction of the inequality, depending on the sign of $xp$.  However, breaking things into four cases is too much work.  Instead, why not simply consider two cases:  (1) $xp > 0$, and (2) $xp < 0$ (note that we cannot have $xp = 0$, as the original rational expression would have been undefined in the first place).  We *might* have to break these cases up more later, depending on where the computation leads us, but why make life messy earlier than we have to?

1. If we assume that $xp > 0$, then we obtain
   $$ x^2 + p^2 < -2xp < 0, $$
   where the final inequality follows from the fact that $xp$ is positive.  Since $x^2$ and $p^2$ are both necessarily nonnegative, this is impossible.  This implies that $xp$ cannot be nonnegative.  That is, this first case cannot occur, and we don't have to do any more work here.
2. If, on the other hand, we assume that $xp < 0$, then we obtain
   $$ x^2 + p^2 > -2xp
   \implies x^2 + 2xp + p^2 > 0
   \implies (x+p)^2 > 0. $$
   This is true for all $x \ne -p$.  Therefore $xp$ must be negative and we must have $x \ne -p$.

Combining the above results, we get the set of solutions
$$ \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \mid xp < 0 \text{ and } x \ne -p \}. $$
Alternatively, we could describe this as the set of $x$ such that the sign of $x$ differs from the sign of $p$, and $x\ne -p$.